# Pxssh reconnect Python (pexpect)

Tags: python, pexpect

I need to do more then one connection in one script using `pxssh`.
Trying to do like this:

```
import pxssh
ip = 'ip'
username = 'username'
password = 'password'
s = pxssh.pxssh()
s.login (ip, username, password)
s.sendline('command')
s.prompt()
print s.before
s.logout()
s.login(ip2, username, password)
etc
```

But getting error on the second connection: `AssertionError: The pid member must be None.`
Only one connection per time is passing.
How to get it work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to create a new pxssh object. The constructor for the pxssh object creates a process and spawns ssh. Logout disconnects from the remote system, which makes the connection useless but doesn't reset the object. Something like this:

```
...
s.logout()
s.close()
s = pxssh.pxssh()
s.login(ip2, ...)
```

The s.close() is not strictly necessary but it's a good idea as otherwise, the underlying file descriptor will not be closed until the original object is garbage-collected.